# Custom Index Swashbuckle/Swagger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

this is my first time using Swagger, I'm currently using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v2.4.0 and trying to implement a custom index page. In this version they have removed the possibility of injecting javascript, and I'm essentially stuck with the only option of making a custom index.html page just to edit some links (most specifically the navigation icon link). I'm trying to get my custom index page to work but I'm having trouble getting it to load.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly
        .GetManifestResourceStream("customSwaggerIndex.html"); // requires file to be added as an embedded resource
});
```

I have the following in my code with the `customSwaggerIndex.html` saved on the wwwroot folder and its Build Action set as Embedded resource, but I keep running into the error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null`. This is most likely due to me not properly writing the GetManifestResourceStream("string"). Any help?

Comment: Have you tried lowercasing everything? Embedded resource filenames are lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out why it wasn't working. First thing is that it needs the name of the solution, and instead of `\` its `.`

So for example a file located in my wwwroot folder would look like this.

```
c.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly
        .GetManifestResourceStream("MySolution.wwwroot.customSwaggerIndex.html");
```